# Spring Meta-Annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Does anybody know what Spring `JAR` (**and where to find it!**) contains the functionality for Spring's so-called "*meta-annotations*". As [this](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/05/06/spring-framework-30-m3-released/) article shows, these cool "new" (well, sorta) constructs allow code like this:

```
@Service
@Scope("request")
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyService {
}

@MyService
public class RewardsService {
    …
}
```

Basically, I have a Swing app that **does not** currently use Spring. I have a sudden requirement change that would be made supremely-easier if I could use these annotations.

So I'm just looking for the smallest, minimally-invasive Spring `JAR` where this functionality can be found. If absolute-need-be, I can use the entire Spring `JAR`, but it would be a very heavy-handed solution. It would be nice if Spring released a smaller `JAR` with smaller-scope functionality.

I'm browswing Maven Repo and see `spring-core` which contains a package called:

> org.springframework.core.annotation

But upon inspection of the API docs it doesn't seem to be what I need...

**Ancillary question:** is it even possible to use these meta-annotations as standalone constructs, or do I *have* to use them along with, say, Spring DI or AOP or other major parts of the Spring framework?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would an annotation work without the code that does something with the annotations? An annotation is just that--a note, meta-data, that can be used by other code. It doesn't do anything on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotations you want will be with the jar it is related to. For instance, the annotation `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` will be in the `spring-transactions` artifact.

Meta-annotations are not really different from regular annotations other than the fact that Spring now detects Annotations on annotations whereas it didn't before. Whether annotations "work" or not depends on what is looking for them (in this case something in the Spring context).

For further reading see [Annotation-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) in the Spring framework reference.

Comment: Thanks Dev - it might be because its late and I've been up all day, I'm just having a little bit of trouble understanding your response. Are you saying that there is no *one place* where these "meta-annotations" are defined, or are you surmising that they are rooted somewhere inside of `spring-context`? Thanks again!

Comment: The annotations themselves are defined in whatever jars they are defined in. `spring-context` contains the framework that makes the annotations work. I amended my answer to provide you with further reading on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

There is project on github which is trying to provide meta-annotation functionality.
https://github.com/dblevins/metatypes/